# Logitech Webcam 300 Freezes

Tags: windows-7, logitech-webcam

My Logitech Webcam 300 freezes.

Windows 7 machine.  Fully patched, Secunia gives 100% secure score.  Driver up-to-date, device manager says 'This device is working properly'  (It lies!).

Symptoms: Start Logitech HD Vid, or Logitech Webcam and camera freezes.  Light comes on above lens, application interface launches with a black screen waiting for a video picture.  Machine completely frozen, unresponsive, even Ctr Alt Del does not respond, only way out is a hardware reset - nasty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that the problem was hardware error.  Lots of coruption revealed by sfc /scannow.

Also nobody else has experienced the same problem, therefore not a Logitech bug.